# Why doesn't application of function returned by elisp macro work?

Tags: emacs, macros, elisp

For example, here is a macro:

```
(defmacro my-macro (x y)
  (if (> x 0) 
  `(lambda (z) (+ z ,y))
`(lambda (z) (+ ,x z))))
```

and `(my-macro 2 3)` returns `(lambda (z) (+ z 3))`

However, `((my-macro 2 3) 1)` returns an error saying,

```
 Debugger entered--Lisp error:

 (invalid-function (my-macro 2 3))
  ((my-macro 2 3) 1)
  eval(((my-macro 2 3) 1))
  eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if you're happy with the help given. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Emacs Lisp requires the first element of a list [form](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Forms.html#Forms) to be a built-in function (or [subr](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Forms.html#Special-Forms)), a [lambda-expression](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Forms.html#Function-Forms) (i.e. `(lambda LIST . LIST)`) or a [macro lambda-expression](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Macro-Forms.html#Macro-Forms) (i.e. `(macro lambda LIST . LIST)`). The first element can also be a [symbol](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Indirection.html#Function-Indirection) whose function slot contains a valid first element.

`(my-macro 2 3)` doesn't have the required form, so it's an invalid function.

If you're used to Scheme, where the function part of a function call is evaluated normally, note that this can't work identically in Lisp where functions have a different namespace (`(f 3)` looks up `f`'s function slot, whereas the value of `f` is normally its value slot).

If you want to evaluate a function like a normal value, you can use [`funcall` or `apply`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html#Calling-Functions).

```
(funcall (my-macro 2 3) 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message makes clear, in evaluating the form `((my-macro 2 3) 1)`, Emacs doesn't expand `(my-macro 2 3)` before evaluating the list it's the first element of.  You want to say

```
(funcall (my-macro 2 3) 1)
```

or

```
(eval (list (my-macro 2 3) 1)
```

or something like that, so that the macro gets evaluated.